# Is it possible to optimize a database check?

Tags: php

I have been studying the PHP manual today, I couldn't locate a section where I could check an input which could be a username or email address during post from one field input from a form.

I figured it out and the code below works, I can either use a username or email address to login with a password, but I can't help but feel it could be optimized as I'm checking the `$_POST['user_email']` twice.

If anyone could point me in the right direction or provide some advice just so I can keep to the best possible coding standard, I'd really appreciate it.

```
if ($_POST) {
include_once "database.php";
include_once "user.php";
$database = new Database\Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();
$user = new User\User($db);

$user->email = $_POST['user_email'];
$email_exists = $user->emailExists();
$user->username = $_POST['user_email'];
$username_exists = $user->usernameExists();

if ($username_exists || $email_exists && password_verify($_POST['password'], $user->password) && $user->status == 1) {
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
} else {
    $access_denied = true;
}
}
```

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: Usually I check that the username/email exists and password is valid in the same query.  `WHERE username = ? AND password = ?`

Comment: Ditch emailExists, usernameExists calls and just select the user by email or username. then do check on password when/if you get a user result back. How is `$user->status` etc getting set?

Comment: @JasonK I'm not using any framework, just raw php.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thank you, I'll have a look into that.

Comment: Can you post your user class so we can see how everything is set?